# using qTip inside asp.net listview itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview, itemtemplate, qtip

I am trying to use **[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)** inside an ASP.NET ListView. The page uses a MasterPage. There is an Image in each Item which will show a DataBound value when hovered.

Below is my ItemTemplate code:

```
<ItemTemplate> 

    <p> 
        <%# Eval("Name")%>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Image ID="imgInfo" runat="server" 
                   align="right" 
                   ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/question.png" />
    </p> 

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" 
                 TextMode="MultiLine" 
                 Rows="4" 
                 SkinID="dummy" 
                 Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>' />

    <asp:Label ID="lblHelpText" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Eval("HelpText")%>'  
               Visible="false" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

        $('[#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvStep1_imgInfo_0]').qtip({ 

            content: 'the tooltip text, I want text of lblHelpText here', 
            style: { name: 'blue' } 

        });

    </script> 

</ItemTemplate>
```

My Questions:

1. This way the Id has been hard
   coded, so works just on one item. I
   could not find a selector that would
   select the Ids for me.
2. I need the lblHelpText.Text or
   <%# Eval("HelpText")%> as the
   tooltip text (content : )
3. Since the script is within the
   ItemTemplate, it would be created as
   many times the number of items. Is
   there a way I can achieve all this
   by having script at one place
   (outside ItemTemplate)?

Your help will be most appreciated,

Ali

Answer (score 1):

You could do it outside of the listview but you need to refactor your design; you need a global HTML element wrapping the entire item, such as:

```
<div class='ItemContainer'>
  .
  .
</div>
```

And refactor your script:

```
$("#<%= listview.ClientID %>").find("<div.ItemContainer").each(function(i) {
   var img = $(this).find("img:first");
   //give the label a CSS class of.HelpText to make it easier to find
   var content = $(this).find("span.HelpText").html();

   $(img).qtip({ 

            content: content, 
            style: { name: 'blue' } 

        });
});
```

Something like that.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply assign a class to your images and then bind the help text into the title attribute of the image.

ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgInfo" runat="server" 
    CssClass="listViewImage" align="right" 
    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/question.png" />
```

Binding:

```
((Image)MyListView.Controls.Find("imgInfo")).Title = HelpText;
```

You could also do this in your markup if you prefer if you're not binding via code:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgInfo" runat="server" 
    CssClass="listViewImage" align="right" 
    Title='<%# Eval("HelpText")%>'
    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/question.png" />
```

qTip Init (qTip uses title tag if present as content by default):

```
$('img.listViewImage').qtip({
    style: { 
        name: 'blue'
    }
});
```

If you don't want to use the title tag, you could use the "alt" or "rel" attribute, which would be performed the same way.  Alternatively, you could contain the text in a hidden element.  That'd be a bit more complex and might be done something like this:

ItemTemplate:

```
<span class="listViewImage">
    <asp:Image ID="imgInfo" runat="server" 
        align="right" 
        ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/question.png" />
    <span class="helpText" style="display: none;"><%# Eval("HelpText")%></span>
</span>
```

qTip Init (qTip uses title tag if present as content by default):

```
$('span.listViewImage img').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: $(this).find('span.helpText').html(),
        style: { 
            name: 'blue'
        }
    });
});
```

Edit:

Forgot to mention, with these solutions, you'd move the javascript outside of your item template.